# Maxima CAS get Parametric equations of 3D surface from points

Tags: parametric, parametrization, maxima-software

I am new to Maxima CAS. I briefly looked at the Maxima manual, but it is quite overwhelming. So, before I delve into the details, I thought to ask: can Maxima obtain the parametric equations for an irregular 3D shape from points?

Thank you!